# Why literals are considered expressions in C++?

Tags: c++, variables, expression, literals

I'm studying the C++ programming language using Programming priciples and practice using C++.
 I'm in chapter 4 now and in this chapter the book introduces the concept of expression, but I can't understand it at all :

> The most basic building block in a program is an expression. An espression compute a value from a number of operands. The simplest expression in C++ is simply a literal value such as 11, 'c', "hello". Names of variables are also expressions. A variable represent the object which it is the name.

Why a literal is considered an expression ? Why the name of a variable is considered an expression ?

Comment: An expression is anything that has a value.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: Even if the type of that value is `void`.

Comment: All the folks voting for "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error." are clearly misusing the system. This isn't caused by a problem that cannot be reproduced, nor by a typographical error, and in fact I'll go so far as saying I think it's a perfectly valid question that deserves to stay up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expressions -in programming languages, in math, in linguistics- are defined compositionally (or inductively). So expressions are often made of subexpressions like `x*2+y*4` is made of two sub-expressions `x*2` and `y*4` joined by the addition operator `+`.

But you need a base case (the most atomic and simple expressions). These are literals (`2`) and variables (`x`) - if either of them was not an expression `2*x` could not be an expression (since both operands of the binary multiplication `*` are sub-expressions).

Notice that in C and C++ *assignments* and *function calls* are expressions

Comment: why the name of a variable is an expression ? I can't understand it, i understand literals but the lvalue and rvalu topics on my book are confusing me, a variable is an expression because it can be used as an operand like literals ?

Comment: @pieroborrelli It is very likely that your book uses the terms lvalue and rvalue in an incorrect fashion. May I ask what book you are using, and how it defines the terms lvalue and rvalue?

Comment: @FredOverflow  my book is programming principles and practice using C++, the definition of lvalue is that for example when i use a variable on the left hand side of assignment that's the lvalue of that variable (the box named by that variable), when i put a variable on the right hand side of the assignment that's the rvalue of that variable (the value in the object).

Answer (score 2):

Think of it like this: An expression is a sequence of steps that produce a value. Thus, `4+3` is a two-step expression, because you (1) start with the number `4`, and (2) add `3` to it.

Therefore, `7` can be regarded as a *single-step* sequence, because there is only one "action" performed: (1) start with the number `7`.

Thus, both `a = 4+3;` and `a = 7;` can be generalised to `a = <expression>;`.

Comment: C has sequence points precisely because expressions are not an ordered  *sequence* of steps. Otherwise, `(++i)-(i--)` or `printf("%d %d\n", i++, i++)` would not be undefined behavior

Answer (score 1):

An expression is "a sequence of operators and operands that specifies a computation" (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/expressions).

Let see a simple expression: 3 + 3. When you evaluate this expression, you will get the result 6.

So let see another expression: 3. When you evaluate this expression, you will get the result 3.

A literal is considered an expression because a literal is a type of constant and constants are expressions with a fixed value.

A variable is also considered as an expression because it can be used as an operand within another expression or as an expression by itself.

In software design, composite pattern can be used as a representation of the expression.